# Como filtrar, copiar lo filtrado a otra columna

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, numpy

estoy haciendo un filtro de un dataFrame en una una columna(MES) y pegando lo filtrado en otra columna(Clas Inventario) del mismo dataFrame, pero cuando realizo otro filtro en columna(AÑO) para pegar eso filtrado a la misma columna(Clas Inventario) me remplaza todo por los datos del ultimo filtro que realice en la columna(MES)

Quiero que lo filtrado anteriormente no se remplace por el ultimo filtro que se hace.
Ayuda por favor

Tengo el siguiente código

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

plantilla = ('C:/Users/adatos/Desktop/AUTOMATIZACION/AUTOMATIZACION PARAMETRIZACION INVENTARIO/EJEMPLO.xlsx')

df = pd.read_excel(plantilla, header=0)

#Creando columna clasi inventario
df['Clas Inventario'] = 0

#Primer filtro
df['Clas Inventario'] = df['MES'].apply(lambda x: x 
if x == 'ABRIL' or x== 'AGOSTO' or x== 'ENERO' 
else 0)

#Segundo filtro
df['Clas Inventario'] = df['AÑO'].apply(lambda x: x 
if x == 2022
else 0)

#Guardar
df.to_excel('prueba.xlsx',index=False)
```

Este es el resultado del codigo que tengo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el resultado que quiero obtener
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @Esteban Muñoz No entiendo. Columna A B C. filtras A y pones en B. Luego reiteras el filtro? y deber[ia poner en B? y te reemplaza todo?

Comment: Buen día, no es muy claro lo que deseas hacer ni el problema que se presenta, por favor oprime [edit] y agrega algunas filas de tus `dataframe` con las que se pueda reproducir el problema, el resultado obtenido actualmente y un ejemplo del resultado esperado.

Comment: No, lo que quiero hacer es: Filtar en columna X y pegar lo filtrado en columna Y, luego filtar en columna Z y tambien pegarlo en columna Z.       De la forma como lo estoy haciendo cuando filtro en columna X y lo pego en columna Y todo funciona bien, pero cuando filtro en columna Z y lo pego en colomna Y me remplaza los datos que habia pegado por los datos del ultimo filtro de columna Z

Comment: Como ha sido mencionado en el comentario anterior, por favor provee algunas filas de tu `dataframe` con las que se pueda reproducir el problema y reduce el código al mínimo para mostrar el comportamiento erróneo y muestra un ejemplo del comportamiento esperado.

Comment: Ya actualice la pregunta con un código mas pequeño y con el resultado que me esperando y el resultado que quiero tener. Eres espero en pandas o con automatización de Excel usando pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque la pregunta no es muy clara si no entiendo mal quieres aplicar dos operaciones en secuencia que deberían hacer lo siguiente:

1. Escribir en la columna `"Clas Inventario"` el nombre del mes, si éste es ABRIL, AGOSTO o ENERO
2. Escribir en esa misma columna el año si es 2022
3. Escribir en esa misma columna un 0 para el resto de los casos.

Naturalmente no te funciona porque lo que realmente estás haciendo es:

1. Escribir el mes si es ABRIL, AGOSTO o ENERO **o bien un 0 si no es ninguno de esos** (hasta aquí vale)
2. Escribir el año si es 2022 **o bien un 0 si no**

Y obviamente el problema es que estás escribiendo un 0 cuando el año no es 2022, cuando lo que quieres es no escribir nada en ese caso para no perder el nombre del mes que habías escrito en el primer paso.

Y es que un `.apply()` puede que no sea la mejor opción en este caso, puesto que el `.apply()` hace la misma operación con todas las filas y tú sólo quieres hacerla con algunas. Por tanto se trataría más bien de un filtro.

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Rellenar con 0 la columna "Clas Inventario", para tener ya el valor por defecto asignado.
2. Copiar el mes **sólo** de las filas cuyo mes sea uno de los tres buscados
3. Copiar el año **sólo** de las filas cuyo año sea 2022.

Ese "sólo de..." es un filtro.

### Solución

En código sería así:

```
df['Clas Inventario'] = 0

# Copiar el MES solo en las filas en las que el mes sea uno de los dados
df.loc[df.MES.isin(["ABRIL", "AGOSTO", "ENERO"]), "Clas Inventario"] = df.MES

# Copiar el AÑO solo en las filas en las que el año sea 2022
df.loc[df.AÑO == 2022, "Clas Inventario"] = df.AÑO
```

#### Demo

Si preparo el siguiente dataframe de ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"MES": ["ENERO", "FEBRERO", "MARZO", "ABRIL", "MAYO", "JUNIO", "JULIO", "AGOSTO"],
              "AÑO":      [2011,    2012,       2022,    2023,    2022,   2020,   2019,     2018]})
```

---

```
       MES   AÑO
0    ENERO  2011
1  FEBRERO  2012
2    MARZO  2022
3    ABRIL  2023
4     MAYO  2022
5    JUNIO  2020
6    JULIO  2019
7   AGOSTO  2018
```

tras ejecutar el código dado en la solución el dataframe queda así:

```
       MES   AÑO Clas Inventario
0    ENERO  2011           ENERO
1  FEBRERO  2012               0
2    MARZO  2022            2022
3    ABRIL  2023           ABRIL
4     MAYO  2022            2022
5    JUNIO  2020               0
6    JULIO  2019               0
7   AGOSTO  2018          AGOSTO
```

Comment: Me funcione perfectamente amigo, muchas gracias

Comment: Amigo te queria hacer otra consulta y disculpa lo novato pero a penas estoy iniciando en este cuento. Como puedo hacer un filtro multiple, es decir que yo filtre en columna(MES) por X dato  y filtral en columna (Clas Inventario) por dato en 0 y pegas lo filtrado en esa mismas columna(Clas Inventario). Quisas no entiandas lo que necesito pero el dataFrame que tengo que organizar tiene muchos datos los cueles tengo que filtrar en un lado y otro para poder construir el informe

Comment: Ya lo logre de esta forma  df1.loc[(df1['Clas Inventario']==0) & (df1.GRUPO == 'ACCESORIOS'), 'Clas Inventario'] = df1.GRUPO